# how to store 0 in MSB of int datatype in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()


{

    int x = 0101;

    cout<<x;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is 101 but I want 0101 instead. what to do??

Comment: is your `0101` binary number or an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer values are written in
4 forms in C++:

- **Decimal** with digits 0-9: `1590`, `4581`
- **Octal** with digits 0-7 and starting with a leading zero: `043`, `077`
- **Hexadecimal** with digits 0-9 and a-f, starting with a leading `0x` or `0X`: `0xc0d3`, `0X170`
- **Binary** from C++ version 14 onwards with digits zero and one, a leading `0b` or `0B`: `0b1011`, `0B0101`

You number (a.k.a numeric literal) `0101` is in *octal* form (in standard C++ anyway) as it has a leading zero.

As @peru mentioned, you have to convert your number into one of the four supported numeric literal forms mentioned above.

If you have a C++14 compiler, you can do `0b0101` directly. Chances are you have to stick with the other three forms.

Octal and hexadecimal are easier to convert to and from binary. It's a good idea to choose them when working with binary. Five is still five in octal and hexadecimal, of course...

The `cout` stream prints integers in decimal format. So you can look at your compiler documentation to see if there is a binary output option. Alternatively, you can implement it yourself. For an 8 bit number:

```
void print_bin8(int num){

  for(int pos = 7; pos > 0; pos--){
    int bitmask = (1 << pos);
    int bit = num & bitmask;
    
    if(bit != 0){ cout << 1;}
    else{ cout << 0;}
  }
```

Basically mask each bit out with an AND and print it MSB to LSB.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you [should get `65`](https://godbolt.org/z/z9Ef81xb4) as `0101` is parsed as octal `101` (64+1).

---

If you want to use binary literal, you can prepend `0b`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 0b0101;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5Pxqehz7P